# iOS 8 MKAnnotationView Callout Incorrectly Sized

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I have some annotations with titles and subtitles; others with just titles.  When I select an annotation programmatically, I'm often seeing a callout that is incorrectly sized (e.g., generally too tall for the text).  Often, it appears that a view sized to accommodate a subtitle is used for an annotation with just a title.  None of these callouts have accessory views.  Has anyone experienced this problem?  I apparently need to force each accessory view to resize itself when it gets new content, but can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Since I do not see any code in your question, but I assume that the following code that I wrote long time ago might answer your issue.

```
MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [self.mapView viewForAnnotation:annotation];
    // The annotation must be visible, otherwise a refresh isn't needed
    if (annotationView != nil) {
        NSArray *selectedAnnotations = self.mapView.selectedAnnotations;
        // The annotation must be selected, otherwise a refresh isn't needed
        if ((selectedAnnotations != nil) && ([self.mapView.selectedAnnotations indexOfObject:annotation] != NSNotFound)) {
                // Unset and re-set the right button to force relayout
                UIView *view = annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView;
                annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = nil;
                annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = view;
        }
    }
```